# CSS: iframe not displaying 100% height...more like 100px height

Tags: css, iframe, height, width, overflow

Having an issue with this page (http://purcraft.com/madeinla/) which I'm trying to use an iframe element to display the contents of this page: (http://purcraft.com/madeinla/home2_height.html).

The width is good but the height? Seems to be more like 100px rather than the 100% I want. Why is this? Here's my code. It's pretty straightforward.

```
<iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%" src="http://purcraft.com/madeinla/home2_height.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: Try to use value in px for parent div and then use % value for iframe

Comment: As @K.B.M said, iframe height percentage is according to the parent. Your parent is the body, which is only as high as it needs to be. Wrap it in a div and set a height in px on the div. Note: iframe % height is not 100% of contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

Give `position: absolute; and border:none;` to your `IFRAME` along with `height:100%` to get expected result.

**HTML:**

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://purcraft.com/madeinla/home2_height.html" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; border: none"></iframe>
```

Comment: Ah, I just needed to declare positioning! That worked. Thanks so much.

Comment: This resolved a similar issue to me. Thank you. But I don't get how position: absolute; fixed the height issue of a frame.