# iFrame height ignored

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am working with this page:
http://icelandwithkids.com/2016/02/11/do-i-need-a-4wd-awd-4x4-car-in-iceland/

There is an iFrame that provides a Google Map:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m24!1m8!1m3!1d901747.8867442308!2d-19.44933680502082!3d63.804830147198125!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m13!3e6!4m5!1s0x48d74a424936b0d1%3A0xbe83531b006d778d!2sVik%2C+Iceland!3m2!1d63.4186315!2d-19.0060479!4m5!1s0x48d11a6e58c79679%3A0x48dc5b5397a88a8d!2sSveinstindur%2C+Iceland!3m2!1d64.1069444!2d-18.4166667!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1455105815201/" scrolling="yes" class="iframe-class" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

No matter what I do, the height of the iFrame will not change-- it is stuck at a very minimal height. I've tried using a perentage; I've tried some style stuff, as I found on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641823/css-iframe-not-displaying-100-height-more-like-100px-height). But nothing seems to make a difference.

I assume that some CSS elsewhere on the page is preventing the iFrame height option from being used?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your CSS you have:

```
embed,iframe,object,video{
    height:auto !important
}
```

This forces it to be auto no matter what you do.

Also you have an external file that also set the heights of the iframe to `auto !important`

```
cache.skin.css
```

Remove those then you can set your height to whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the first block of code. I'm trying to figure out where the second one is. The cache.skin.css looks like it links to: 

http://icelandwithkids.com/wp-content/themes/piemont/cache/cache.skin.css

But I am not sure I see anything about iFrame in there?

Comment: Remove the height:auto you set in `.blog-post iframe`

Comment: Got it. I see that now in http://icelandwithkids.com/wp-content/themes/piemont/style.css. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that the iframe is inside a div or another size-limiting container. Try increasing the size of the container that the iframe is inside of.